# How to implement Jquery noconflict

Tags: html, css, jquery

I keep getting uncaught type errors with `masonry` on [this site](http://56point2.com/relay/)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

This happens when I scale the browser down.

I'm not sure how to implement

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and will that solve the problem?

Comment: Please post the specific lines of code that are giving you the error and describe what action on your site triggers the error.  As it is, we don't know how to look at the error.  FYI, `jQuery.noConflict()` is fairly thoroughly documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: I'm not getting that error.

Comment: No conflict is generally to allow you to use jQuery and other libraries (like MooTools) at the same time.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the link to my other version of this, which does it more frequently; it happens when you scale the browser down and tries to call masonry.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it normally, I make a copy of my jQuery file - for example: `jquery-1.9.1.noconflict.js` and I append `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of the file so that it is run before anything else even has a chance to run.

After that I use `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias to call everything. I have had much success using this method, especially in conflicts with Prototype, but this should work with conflicts with other libraries too.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery 1.9, the `$.event.handle` method was removed from the library.

The infinitescroll plugin used to use this method for dispatching events up to 3 months ago. You need to make sure you're using the latest & greatest [infinitescroll plugin from Github](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll), or you will need to downgrade to JQuery 1.8 to stop this error appearing.

**Edit**: Ooops, just noticed you are using JQuery 1.6.1 on your site. As you are using other JQuery plugins from 2012, you may want to consider upgrading your JQuery to see if this solves the problem. I still believe it is a problem between the two plugins: infinitescroll and masonry.